# mysql display value if matches or display blank

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Im doing a query in phpmyadmin to create a report file that i want to export and
I have a column in my database name 'title' and it contains either "sub-total", "total", "tax", "shipping" as its value.

How can i tell my query to return rows where the value of title is equal to "tax" and if its not then to return the value as blank.

I don't want to exclude a row if the value of title column is not tax, I want it to display a blank as there is other information needed that is with the rows.

Comment: Have you tried anything before asking your question?

Comment: I have the entire query built already but its including the other values instead of just where the value is equal to tax. At this point I don't know what to do to filter out the values that dont equal tax yet still keep the row.

Comment: Blank meaning it returns no value, if the title column in a row isnt equal to "tax" then i just want it to be blank without filtering out the entire row

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

`` SELECT IF(`title`='tax', `title`, '**blank**')... ``